# Is it possible to set Totem as frontend for Xine?

Tags: gui, video-player, xine

The Wikipedia article for Totem player says that "until version 2.27.1, it could alternatively be configured to use the Xine libraries instead of GStreamer".

I like Xine very much, but not its available GUIs (xine-ui, gxine, kaffeine are so awkward that I still prefer to stick with VLC, SMPlayer, Totem or Gnome Player).

Is it a way to make one of the most used "players" - especially Totem, maybe, but the present version 3.4 might not allow it - be used as a fronted for the Xine engine (xine-lib)?

(Also, is there a new GUI for Xine that I have not mentioned? The others listed [here](http://www.xine-project.org/releases) are abandoned.)

Comment: Please limit your questions to one question _per_ question, instead of asking multiple questions in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totem can no longer be used as a front-end for Xine, and going forward will probably be even more tightly tied to Gstreamer.

Xine is not as popular as it once was (in fact, it's [pretty much dead](http://wm161.net/2011/09/08/phonon-xine-is-dead-long-live-phonon-gstreamer/)), so finding a "modern" GUI for Xine is essentially impossible, unless someone writes a new one. I would suggest sticking with VLC, or Gnome-Mplayer.

Unfortunately your options, though varied, will not offer much of anything new and exciting, so to speak.

Comment: as the other question was closed, would you please comment here? we have gstreamer, with totem frontend; are there other well known frontends for that? the mplayer situation is clear to me; is vlc completely independent of gstreamer?

Comment: @cipricus I don't mind answering you, but it is better to ask these questions on the site (multiple questions may seem tedious but are more useful to yourself and others in the future. Comments are not for extended discussion or answer questions and will be cleaned up if they go on and on or are used for the wrong purposes).

Comment: ...and yes, VLC is independent of gstreamer. It depends on other libraries such as FFmpeg. There are other frond ends for gstreamer, such as Banshee and Parole.