# On what (main) "engines" are based Ubuntu video players?

Tags: gui, vlc, mplayer, gstreamer, xine

Thinking about using Xine, beside other players like VLC and the mplayer-based ones, I became interested in this and  tried to understand this kind of terminology (player, frontend, gui, engine, etc), as they are used for example in the Xine-ui help:

[image]

For example, a question might be "is Totem a GUI/frontend of Gstreamer?"; but I do not want necessarily an answer to a such question here: but **in order to create separate questions like "what video players are based on the X engine?" I need to know which are the main engines used by Ubuntu video players**.

Comment: You need to change this question to "what engine X application use" so that this not become a useless list of repeated answers and it is better defined.

Comment: That is not the purpose of the site: 1 question > 1 correct answer (most of the times, depending on the number of affected releases). The way you are asking sounds like *Give me all possible video libraries used by all video players ever*. That is not a good question for us.

Comment: Not sure if they are that many actually, for the main video players I know those would be the ones in use, but making it more specific would give you more specific answers for your needs. Can we do that?

Comment: Oh this is becoming confusing: are you trying to find out what video libs are used by an certain application or how many there are? Why?

Comment: @BrunoPereira:"Why?": just to know. i want to know this, i am curious how main video players are different according to each engine. and as i expect that there  are not so many "engines", **here** i ask which are these engines. about players for **each** engine i might ask in separate questions

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org

Comment: This *really* needs some clarification.  What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

The default "main" video player in Ubuntu is `totem` and it uses GStreamer as the multimedia framework.

Comment: in a comment here (http://askubuntu.com/a/261543/47206) i see that also Banshee and Parole use it